# Changing order of summation with Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Let $\mu(d)$ be the Möbius function, and $\mu_r(d)$ be the modified Möbius function which satisfies $\mu_r(d)=0$ if $d$ has strictly more than $r$ distinct prime factors. Let $\psi_r(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu_r(d)$. Finally, we let $P_z$ be the product of all primes less than or equal to $z$. Then, what I am humbly requesting help with proving, is 
$$
\sum_{d\mid P_z}\frac{1}{d}\sum_{\delta\mid d}\mu(d/\delta)\psi_r(\delta) = 
\sum_{\delta\mid P_z}\frac{\psi_r(\delta)}{\delta}\sum_{d\mid P_z/\delta}
\frac{\mu(d)}{d}.
$$
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\newcommand\1{\mathbf 1}\newcommand\id{\text{id}}$that $\psi_r=\1*\mu_r$, so $\mu*\psi_r=\mu_r$ by Möbius inversion. Therefore the LHS equals
$$\begin{align}\sum_{d\mid P_z}\frac1d\cdot\mu_r(d)
&=\frac1{P_z}\sum_{d\mid P_z}\mu_r(d)\frac{P_z}d\\
&=\frac1{P_z}(\mu_r*\id)(P_z).\end{align}$$

The RHS is

$$\begin{align}\sum_{\delta\mid P_z}\frac{\psi_r(\delta)}{P_z}\sum_{d\mid P_z/\delta}\mu(d)\frac{\frac{P_z}\delta}d
&=\sum_{\delta\mid P_z}\frac{\psi_r(\delta)}{P_z}(\mu*\id)(P_z/\delta)\\
&=\frac1{P_z}(\psi_r*(\mu*\id))(P_z)\\
&=\frac1{P_z}((\psi_r*\mu)*\id)(P_z)\\
&=\frac1{P_z}(\mu_r*\id)(P_z).\end{align}$$

This is exactly the same as the LHS.

Comment: Note that I didn't use any properties of $\mu_r$ or $\psi_r$ besides $\psi_r=\mathbf 1*\mu_r$. Your equality is in fact true for any pair of arithmetic functions $f,g$ satisfying $f=1*g$.